# Tesseract dont recognize captcha in png file, which contains numbers and letters of the English alphabet

Tags: perl, ocr, tesseract, captcha

I need to extract captcha from url and recognised it with Tesseract. My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -X
###
$user = 'user'; #Enter your username here
$pass = 'pass'; #Enter your password here
###
#Server settings
$home = "http://perltest.adavice.com";
$url = "$home/c/test.cgi?u=$user&p=$pass";
#Get HTML code!
$html = `GET "$url"`
###Add code here!
#Grab img from HTML code
if ($html =~ m%img[^>]*src="(/[^"]*)"%s)
{
    $img = $1;
}
###
die "<img> not found\n" if (!$img);
#Download image to server (save as: ocr_me.img)
print "GET '$home$img' > ocr_me.img\n";
system "GET '$home$img' > ocr_me.img";
###Add code here!
#Run OCR (using shell command tesseract) on img and save text as ocr_result.txt
system("tesseract ocr_me.img ocr_result");
print "GET '$txt' > ocr_result.txt\n";
system "GET '$txt' > ocr_result.txt";
###
die "ocr_result.txt not found\n" if (!-e "ocr_result.txt");
# check OCR results:
$txt = 'cat ocr_result.txt';
$txt =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+//sg;
$img =~ s/^.*\///;
print `echo -n "file=$img&text=$txt" | POST "$url"`;
```

Image parse correctly. This image contain captcha and looks like:

[image: My image PNG file, which contains a captcha]

My output is:

```
GET 'http://perltest.adavice.com/captcha/1533110309.png' > ocr_me.img
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02.02 with Leptonica
GET '' > ocr_result.txt
Captcha text not specified
```

As you see, script parse image correctly. But Tesseract didnt see anything in that PNG file. I am trying to specify additional parameters such as -psm and -l with shell command tesseract, but this also giving nothing

**UPDATE**: After read answer @Dave Cross, I am tried his suggestion.

In output I got:

```
http://perltest.adavice.com/captcha/1533141024.png
ocr_me.img
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02.02 with Leptonica
[]
200Captcha text not specified
Original image file not specified
Captcha text not specified
```

Why I need text from image .PNG?  Maybe this additional information can help you. 
Look at that:
[image]

This is how $url looks like in browser. My goal here is create query for this page in wim using perl. For this I need fill in forms above my $user, $pass and $txt (from recognized with Tesseract image). And send that with POST 'url' (last string in code).

Comment: Are you sure it didn't? What does the file "ocr_result" contain?

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined $txt anywhere so you have an empty ocr_result.txt

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of all your scripts, and initialise variables with `my` (e.g. `my $variable`) to help eliminate simple errors.

Comment: @Chris Turner, "ocr_result" need to contain the text from captcha. But in my previous code as I can see, I get nothing text from Tesseract to this file

Comment: @i alarmed alien, thanks for your suggestion. Added strict and warnings in my code

Comment: My point was more that tesseract was writing out to "ocr_result", but you were looking for the result in "ocr_result.txt" which is a different file.

Comment: @ChrisTurner: I thought that too. But reading the man page for tesseract, it says that parameter is the "basename of the output file" and it gets .txt appended to it.

Comment: @Oysiyl: You need to give `tesseract` the special string `stdout` (not the filename) for my code to work. Attention to detail is a vital part of the programmer's work :-)

Comment: @Oysiyl: I see you've updated the code following my last suggestion. Is the output now out of date?

Comment: @Dave Cross, still the same( Captcha text not specified. Maybe I am add my real user and pass information to code? Can this help?

Comment: @Oysiyl: You need to take this a step at a time. There's no point in trying to `POST` the data until you know the correct string is in `$txt`. So we need to work out why `tesseract` doesn't do the OCR for you when it works perfectly for me. Have you checked the contents of `ocr_me.img`? Does it contain the image data that you expect?

Comment: @Oysiyl: Think like a programmer.

Comment: @Oysiyl: I wouldn't recommend posting your username and password here. But if you want to email them to me, I can have a closer look at your code. My domain is `perlhacks.com` and my email address is my first name.

Comment: @DaveCross, send you message via email

Comment: @Oysiyl: Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several strange things going on here. Any one of them could be causing your problems.

1. Having `-X` on your shebang line is a terrible idea. It explicitly turns off warnings. I suggest you remove it, add `use warnings` to your code and fix all the problems that reveals (I'd suggest adding `use strict` too, but you'd need to declare all of your variables).
2. I'd recommend using [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple) instead of shelling out to `GET`.
3. Please don't use regexes to parse HTML. Use a real HTML parser instead. [Web::Query](https://metacpan.org/release/Web-Query) is my current favourite.
4. You then run `GET` again, using a variable called `$txt` that doesn't have a value. That's not going to work!
5. `$txt = 'cat ocr_result.txt'` doesn't do what you think it does. You want backticks, not single quotes.

**Update:** Obviously, I don't have access to your username or password, so I can't reconstruct all of your code. But this seems to work fine for accessing the image in your example and extracting the text from it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use LWP::Simple;

my $img_url  = 'http://perltest.adavice.com/captcha/1533110309.png';
my $img_file = 'ocr_me.img';

getstore($img_url, $img_file);

my $txt = `tesseract $img_file stdout`;

say $txt;
```

Here's your actual error:

```
system("tesseract ocr_me.img ocr_result");
print "GET '$txt' > ocr_result.txt\n";
system "GET '$txt' > ocr_result.txt";
```

You ask `tesseract` to write its output to `ocr_result.txt`, but two lines later, you overwrite that file with the output of a failed call to `GET`. I'm not sure what you think that's going to do, but it will trash whatever output `tesseract` has already stored in that file.

**Updated Update:**

Here's my current version of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use LWP::Simple qw[$ua get getstore];
use File::Basename;
###
my $user = 'xxxx'; #Enter your username here
my $pass = 'xxxx'; #Enter your password here
###
#Server settings
my $home = "http://perltest.adavice.com";
my $url = "$home/c/test.cgi?u=$user&p=$pass";
#Get HTML code!
my $html = get($url);
my $img;
###Add code here!
#Grab img from HTML code
if ($html =~ m%img[^>]*src="(/[^"]*)"%s)
{
    $img = $1;
}
my $img_url = $home . $img;
my $img_file = 'ocr_me.img';

getstore($img_url, $img_file);

say $img_url;
say $img_file;

# Looks like tesseract adds two newlines to its output -
# so chomp() it twice!
chomp(my $txt = `tesseract ocr_me.img stdout`);
chomp($txt);

say "[$txt]";

$txt =~ s/\W+//g;

my $resp = $ua->post($url, {
  u    => $user,
  p    => $pass,
  file => basename($img),
  text => $txt,
});

print $resp->code;
print $resp->content;
```

I've changed a few things.

1. Corrected `$img_url` from `$url . $img` to `$home . $img` (this is what was stopping it from getting the correct image).
2. Switched to using LWP::Simple throughout (it's just easier).
3. `chomp`ed (twice!) the output from `tesseract` to remove newlines.
4. Used File::Basename to get the correct filename to pass in the final `POST`.
5. Removed any non-word characters from `$txt` before `POST`ing it.

It still doesn't quite work. It seems to hang waiting for a response from the server. But I'm afraid I've run out of time to help you.

Comment: @Oysiyl you haven't updated it correctly though - note the difference in how Dave is running tesseract and how you're now running it.

Comment: @Chris Turner, I see I am forget stdout. Change code now

Comment: @DaveCross, Thank you for your help! I'll try to be more accurate. Sorry to take so much of your time. Now I see that I incorrectly chose the address and the benefit of my question on this site is not as big as I thought. To execute my request, I need to raise the server with Putty on SSH protocol. Maybe that's why my script does not see the picture..